# CSV to Named Sheets within existing Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv, powershell

So I’ve been at this for a while now and I’ve got various methods (some VBA, others PowerShell) semi working per say…

Quick overview of what I’m trying to accomplish is importing two CSV’s weekly (erasing the old data, headers always remain the same but are different between the two sheets) into two specific Excel Worksheets within the same workbook (Ex sheet1, sheet2, calculation sheet) which has another sheet that then calculates the data. Finally I’d like to export it as PDF.

**Full Explanation:**

Every Monday two queries are exported as .CSV to let’s say `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Data1.CSV & C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Data2.CSV`

I would then like to have the CSV’s data input into their respective worksheets (Data1, Data2) within the workbook `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Calculation.xlsx`

**Data1 would look like this:**

```
COUNT   STATUS  OPERATOR    PRODUCT     WEEK
1       CANCEL  BOB         Product 1   10
65      CLEAR   JIM         Product 2   10
20      SEND    BOB         Product 1   10
58      CC      KRIS        Product 4   10
3       CLEAR   BOB         Product 1   10
11      SEND    SMIT        Product 6   10
6       CANCEL  JASON       Product 7   10
```

**Data2 would look like this:**

```
OPERATOR    CLEARS  SENDS   TOTAL   CR       WEEK
BOB         11      1       12     0.916667  10 
JIM         17      2       19     0.894737  10 
KRIS        9       1       10     0.9       10 
SMITH       22      5       27     0.814815  10 
JASON       25      7       32     0.78125   10
```

The calculation sheet will then recognize the data and process accordingly then export as a PDF. The following Monday, the windows timer service calls a .bat file which then runs this script (VBA or PowerShell) which erases the previous weeks data within this workbook and inputs the new data from the queries.

I’m very open as which language this is written in I have basic knowledge and understating of both PowerShell and VBA. I have not included the code I currently have as I’ve butchered it to try and get it to work within my needs as I have mixed together various methods from researching how to do this.

Hopefully I’ve provided enough information so that someone can point me in the right direction…

Thanks

**EDIT**

As per Chris here's some code I've been trying to utilize, it's probably extremely confusing as I was trying to modify it for my needs versus what it was initially made for:

```
Get-service bits | Select-Object COUNT, STATUS, OPERATOR, PRODUCT, WEEK | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Data1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
Get-service bits | Select-Object COUNT, STATUS, OPERATOR, PRODUCT, WEEK | Export-Excel 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Calculations.xlsx' 

$Results = @()

Import-Excel -Path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Calculations.xlsx' | foreach {
    $Properties = @{
        COUNT = $PSItem.COUNT
        STATUS = $PSItem.STATUS
        OPERATOR = $PSItem.OPERATOR
        PRODUCT = $PSItem.PRODUCT
        WEEK = $PSItem.WEEK
        }
    $Results += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Properties
}
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Data1.csv' | foreach {
    $Properties = @{

          COUNT = $PSItem.COUNT
        STATUS = $PSItem.STATUS
        OPERATOR = $PSItem.OPERATOR
        PRODUCT = $PSItem.PRODUCT
        WEEK = $PSItem.WEEK
        }
    $Results += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Properties
}
$Results | Export-Excel -Path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Calculations.xlsx'
```

Another example I tried:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$XLSFile = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Calculations.xlxs'
$csvFile = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data\Data1.csv'
$Excel.Visible = $true
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($XLSFile)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.sheets.item('Data')
$ExcelWorkSheet.Activate()
# Go to the first empty row
$LastRow = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | ForEach {

$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,1) = $psitem.COUNT
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,2) = $psitem.STATUS
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,3) = $psitem.OPERATOR
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,4) = $psitem.PRODUCT
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,5) = $psitem.WEEK
$LastRow = $LastRow + 1
}

$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()

$path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\"
$xlFixedFormat = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType” -as [type] 
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse 
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$objExcel.visible = $false 
foreach($wb in $excelFiles) 
{ 
 $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + " Weekending " +(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MMM-dd-yyyy') + “.pdf”) 
 $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3) 
 $workbook.Saved = $true 
“saving $filepath” 
 $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath, 1, 2) 
 $objExcel.Workbooks.close() 
} 
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Final example

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$XLSFile = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Calculations.xlsx'
$csvFile = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data1.csv'
$Excel.Visible = $true
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($XLSFile)
$ExcelWorkBook.worksheets.item("Data1").Delete()
# Create a new worksheet
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Add()
# Set the name for the worksheet
$ExcelWorkSheet.Name = "Data1"
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.sheets.item('Data1')
$ExcelWorkSheet.Activate()
# Go to the first empty row
Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | ForEach {

$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,1) = $psitem.COUNT
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,2) = $psitem.STATUS
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,3) = $psitem.OPERATOR
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,4) = $psitem.PRODUCT
$ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($lastRow,5) = $psitem.WEEK
$LastRow = $LastRow + 1
}

$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: What have you written so far? Examples? Code you want help with? If you're asking for someone to whip up your entire script for you, this is not the place to ask.

Comment: Hi Chris, as I said I did not include it as it's quite butchered trying to modify snippets I have found and make them work for my needs and I'm sure it'd be quite confusing. But I will add it as per your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, the first script uses Import/Export-Excel which are not native powershell cmdlets. Those are imported via a 3rd party module, which you may or may not have. Your second script has a few different issues I see, and it seems you cobbled together most of it for your third, which seems okay except for how you try to manipulate the CSV data. Try to narrow your question down to what you're currently working on, what errors you are encountering and specify what you're trying to fix or understand. Blanket questions like "help me fix it" "how do I make  this work" and likewise aren't helpful.

Comment: The biggest issue i'm finding is that I can't find any info on pasting data from a .csv into an existing worksheet, all I've been finding is how to paste the data into a new worksheet within the existing workbook.

Comment: There is a solution involving deserializing csv data into a custom object hashtable then doing individual writes to each cell you want, but believe me, the ComObject model and usage to do that is very, very slow. I would highly recommend you look at the process of creating/generating the data simultaneously for both CSVs rather than write one, copy over.

Answer (score 0):

Filling the target cells one by one using Excel COM interface is very slow. Using Range.Copy  and Sheet.Paste is much faster:

```
    step 1: "ExcelApp.Workbooks.OpenText" to open data.csv file 
    step 2: "ExcelApp.Windows("data").ActiveSheet" to target the data sheet just opened
    step 3: "ActiveSheet.Range" to target the data area
    step 4: "Range.Copy" to copy the source data to the clipboard 
    step 5: "Sheet.Paste" to move the data to the destination
```

C++ version sample code(suppose we already have "pSheetCsvDest" which is our .csv data destination sheet) :

```
//import Excel library
//....

//declaration
Excel::_ApplicationPtr pAppExcel;
Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheetCsvSource;
Excel::RangePtr pRangeCsvSource;

//initialze excel app and open the source csv file
HRESULT hApp = pAppExcel.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Excel::Application));
pAppExcel->Workbooks->OpenText(_bstr_t("data.csv"), 936, 1, xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,    vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, VARIANT_TRUE, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing);

//target the data range
pSheetCsvSource= pAppExcel->Windows->GetItem(_bstr_t("data"))->ActiveSheet;
pRangeCsvSource= pSheetCsvSource->GetRange(_variant_t("Cell1:Cell2"));

//copy the source data
pRangeCsvSource->Copy();

//paste to destination sheet
pSheetCsvDest->Paste();

//close csv source child window
pAppExcel->Windows->GetItem(_bstr_t("data"))->Close();
```